# Chrome is showing strange errors for my React App after installing Router

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router, create-react-app

I'm working on converting a website from a static HTML/CSS/JS site into a React SPA and I want to use React Router for navigation. I installed Router into the correct directory, ran `npm start` from the correct directory, and my Terminal shows that everything compiled successfully, but my browser looks like this: [image]

App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className = "App">
      <div id ='container' className = 'container light'>
      <Navbar />
      </div>
        
      </div>
    )
    
  }
}



export default App;
```

Navbar.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../styles/App.css';
import logo from '../img/logo.png'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import App from '../App';
import About from './About';
import Portfolio from './Portfolio';

class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="Navbar">
                    <nav>
                        <ul className="navlist">
                            <Link to={App}>
                                <li className="active">Home</li>
                            </Link>
                            <Link to={About}>
                                <li>About Me</li>
                            </Link>
                            <Link to={App}>
                                <img className="brand" src={logo} alt="" />
                            </Link>
                            <Link to={Portfolio}>
                                <li>Portfolio</li>
                            </Link>
                            <li className="toggler"><span role="img" aria-label="dark moon"></span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path= {About}>
                            <About />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path= {Portfolio}>
                            <Portfolio />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path= '{App}'>
                            <App />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

About.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../styles/App.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar'

class About extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="About">
                <Navbar />
                <h1>Hello World, This is the About Page</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default About;
```

Portfolio.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../styles/App.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar'

class Portfolio extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Portfolio">
                <Navbar />
                <h1>Hello World, This is the Portfolio Page</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

I'm new to React and I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Happy to share any additional information needed.

Comment: Ciao, can you show us About component code?

Comment: Hi, can you post *actual* code? Starting with `App` component, tracing all the way to the component calling `locationUtils`, including `About` component/code? Can't debug code that isn't present.

Comment: Updated to show the actual code -- I don't have any components calling `locationUtils`, that's the weird thing -- those location functions in the screenshot aren't anything I've written, and the path shown to `Desktop/modules/etc` isn't the project directory I'm working in. That's why it's weird and I can't figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `Link` is used, the `to` prop should have the path you want to navigate, and then you have to use the `Route` HOC with two options, pass the component as a child or in the `component` prop

**Link**

```
<Link to="/about">
  About
</Link>
```

**Route**

```
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
```

```
<Route path="/about">
  <About/>
</Route>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly, I'm still figuring out Router so sorry if it was a stupid question haha thank you so much!

Comment: There are no stupid questions, glad I could help you, also maybe you wanna start here https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start